# Create shared parameter file for C and Python

Tags: c, python-3.x

> I need to create a parameter file that can be managed across a Python 3.7 and a C code base. This file needs to be modifiable either by the C or the Python program with the changes being taking effect on the other software (an update function will handle reading the updated file). It's best if the file is not human readable, as it contains information that is better left obfuscated.

**Is there a recommended method to do so? **

I could create separate  python and C files, but the set of parameters will change over time (for code maintenance), and the values would be changed by these programs. The list would also be very long. It would be a hassle to maintain two different files and update them over time. Also, the file may need to be exchanged between users, such that a version modified by the software ran by user1 needs to be readable by the software run by user2. The idea is that other parts of both codes could access parts of the parameter list without knowing the full contents of the list.

To clarify the example, I could have a `parameter.h` file containing:

```
struct {
  double par1 =1.1;
  int par 2   =2;
} par_list
```

And I could have a `parameter.py` with:

```
class par_list:
    def(__self__):
        self.par1 = double(1.1)
        self.par2 = int(2)
```

Then, by doing a import in Python or a include in C, I could initialize the parameter list. But in this case the parameters are being read on different files.

I'm considering using some kind of binary file to keep the values, and create a script that writes both the Python and C code that reads and updates the values. I'm concerned because the binary file would need to be interchangeable between ARM architecture running Linux, and x86 architecture running Windows.

Comment: Serialization protocols? XDR?

Comment: [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) could be simplest. A neat C library exists and in Python it is dead simple with the `msgpack` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example working with `numpy`:

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Struct_format{
    uint8_t the_unsigned_int8;
    int32_t the_signed_int32[2];
    double the_double;
};

typedef struct Struct_format upperStruct;

//Use separate file to define default value:

void printStruct(upperStruct test_struct){
    printf("test_struct.the_unsigned_int8 = %d\n", test_struct.the_unsigned_int8);
    printf("test_struct.the_signed_int32[0]  = %d\n", test_struct.the_signed_int32[0]);
    printf("test_struct.the_signed_int32[1]  = %d\n", test_struct.the_signed_int32[1]);
    printf("test_struct.the_double        = %f\n", test_struct.the_double);
}

void main(){
    //Define a "default" value:
    upperStruct fromC2Python = {4U,{-3,-1},2.1};

    printf("Printing fromC2Python\n");
    printStruct(fromC2Python);

    //Save this default in a file:
    FILE * fid = fopen("fromC2Python.bin","w");
    fwrite((void *)&fromC2Python, sizeof(fromC2Python) ,1, fid);
    fclose(fid);

    //Now load the file created by Python:
    upperStruct fromPython2C;
    FILE * fid_py = fopen("fromPython2C.bin","r");
    fread(&fromPython2C, sizeof(fromPython2C) ,1, fid_py);
    fclose(fid_py);

    printf("Printing fromPython2C\n");
    printStruct(fromPython2C);

}
```

Python code:

```
import numpy


datatype = numpy.dtype([('potato',
                                  [('time', numpy.uint8),
                                   ('sec', numpy.int32, 2)]),
                        ('temp', numpy.float64)],
                       align=True)
fromPython2C = numpy.array([((5, (-6, -7)), 61.55)], dtype=datatype)

print(fromPython2C)

fromPython2C.tofile("fromPython2C.bin", sep="")

fromC2Python = numpy.fromfile("fromC2Python.bin", dtype=datatype, count=-1, sep="")

print(fromC2Python)
print(fromC2Python['potato'])
print(fromC2Python['potato']['time'])
print(fromC2Python['temp'])
```

The ideia is that `numpy` allows reading and writing to structured binary files. Hence, it suffices to create the `dtype` specification with a text parser.